# Ruby on Rails parse api to save to db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am practicing with apis in RoR. I am trying to save only a few items from the api call `id, length, dip, name`  but how do I parse it and save the fields that I need and do they need to be in params? Currently the api call data is not in params.

On button click I want to have those fields listed above save into the db

routes

```
  root 'welcome#index'
  post 'search_campaigns', to: 'campaigns#search_all_campaigns'
```

my model

```
class Campaign < ApplicationRecord
  def self.get_your_campaigns
    uri = URI.parse("https://example.site/api/v2/users")
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
    request.content_type = "application/json"
    request.basic_auth("example@email.com", "238urfs393kmdsb2189aead01")
    req_options = {
      use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
    }
    response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
      http.request(request)
    end
    return JSON.parse(response.body)
  end
end
```

controller

```
class CampaignsController < ApplicationController

  def search_all_campaigns
    @campaigns = Campaign.get_your_campaigns
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

view

```
  <%= button_to 'Get All Campaigns', search_campaigns_path %>
```

This how the api call data looks

```
[{"id"=>2758, "dip"=>"2.0", "length"=>10, "name"=>"Cereal", "total_remaining"=>100, "status"=>6, "is_retarget"=>false}, {"id"=>278563, "dip"=>"1.25", "length"=>2, "name"=>"Pizza", "total_remaining"=>123, "status"=>6, "supplier_link"=>"http://www.developingmedia.com/adhoc.php?id=", "incidence"=>50, , "days_in_field"=>5, "max_daily_completes"=>nil, "is_retarget"=>false}, {"id"=>278564, "dip"=>"4.25", "length"=>25, "name"=>"California", "days_in_field"=>5,}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say the API and therefore you `Campaign.get_your_campaigns` method returns a `Hash`that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id" => 2758, 
    "dip" => "2.0", 
    "length" => 10, 
    "name" => "Cereal", 
    "total_remaining" => 100, 
    "status" => 6, 
    "is_retarget" => false
  }, 
  {
    "id" => 278563, 
    "dip" => "1.25", 
    "length" => 2, 
    "name" => "Pizza", 
    "total_remaining" => 123, 
    "status" => 6, 
    "supplier_link" => "http://www.developingmedia.com/adhoc.php?id=", 
    "incidence" => 50, , 
    "days_in_field" => 5, 
    "max_daily_completes" => nil, 
    "is_retarget" => false
  }, 
  { 
    "id" => 278564, 
    "dip" => "4.25", 
    "length" => 25, 
    "name" => "California", 
    "days_in_field" => 5,
  }
]
```

You can use [`Hash#slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Hash.html#method-i-slice) to extract only the attributes you are interested in. And then pass those attributes one after the other to the create method:

```
campaigns_hashes = Campaign.get_your_campaigns    
campaigns_attributes = campaigns_hashes.map { |hash| hash.slice(:id, :name, :length, :dip) }
campaigns = campaigns_attributes.each { |attributes| Campaign.create(attributes) }
```

Note: You will very likely need to add some error handling to this, for example, to deal with invalid data returned from the API or the handle records that have already been imported to avoid duplicates.

Comment: thank you! this got me in the right direction but I kept getting undefined method for map. so I instead was able to do JSON::parse(campaigns_hases) and iterate over that and save it to the db

Comment: I am confused because in your example code you already had a JSON parse.

Comment: actually, yeah your solution worked I think I just made it harder on myself because I took out the JSON Parse from the model and put it in the controller before you responded with a solution lol.